# How is arithmetic defined in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

I wanted to start learning about category theory and wanted to become at least a bit informed about how one might interpret things like arithmetic and other basic operations, thanks, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: See Math Made Difficult by Linderholm.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what category theory is.  It's just another area of math.  If you were going to study topology, would you want to know how to define arithmetic in topology?  (It turns out that there are some senses in which arithmetic can be "defined" in category theory, but this really isn't a question you should be asking at this point.)